# GridView is not Swiping

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I created a ListView defined like this:

```
            <ListView     x:Name="libraryListView"
                      AutomationProperties.AutomationId="VideoListView"
                      AutomationProperties.Name="Videos"
                      TabIndex="1"
                      Padding="0,0,4,0"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                      IsSwipeEnabled="False"
                      SelectionChanged="LibraryListView_SelectionChanged"
                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LibraryItemTemplate}"
                      ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource LibraryListViewItemStyle}">
        </ListView>
```

and the LibraryItemTemplate is define like this:

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="LibraryItemTemplate">

        <Grid Height="191"
              UseLayoutRounding="True">
            <Grid.Background>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill"
                            ImageSource="Assets/BookShelf.jpg" />
            </Grid.Background>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid x:Name="gridTitle"
                  Background="{Binding Text, Converter={StaticResource LibraryItemBackgroundConverter}, ElementName=tbTitle}"
                  Margin="36,4,18,14">

                <TextBlock x:Name="tbTitle"
                           TextWrapping="Wrap"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                           Width="130"
                           Margin="0,0,0,0.2"
                           TextAlignment="Center"
                           FontSize="18.667"
                           FontWeight="Bold"
                           UseLayoutRounding="False"
                           d:LayoutRounding="Auto">
                    <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform Rotation="-90" />
                    </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                    <Run Text="{Binding Title}" />
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>

            <Grid x:Name="gridBooks"
                  Grid.Column="1"
                  Margin="0">

                <!--<local:BooksUC />-->

                <GridView x:Name="booksGridView"
                          AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
                          AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                          ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource textbookTemplateSelector}"
                          SelectionMode="Multiple"
                          IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                          ItemClick="booksGridView_ItemClick"
                          SelectionChanged="booksGridView_SelectionChanged"
                          IsSwipeEnabled="True"
                          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
                          ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled="False"
                          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
                          ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled="False">

                    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                </GridView>

            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

the outcome of the page looks like this:

[image: Screen Capture]

The problem I am seeing is that the GridView is swiping to the left. There are 15 elements in the first shelf.

Any idea what is wrong with my XAML code?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two problems with the LibraryItemTemplate:

1. Changed the Column Definition
2. Changed the ItemsPanel

The code for the template is:

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="LibraryItemTemplate">

        <Grid Height="191"
              UseLayoutRounding="True">
            <Grid.Background>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill"
                            ImageSource="Assets/BookShelf.jpg" />
            </Grid.Background>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid x:Name="gridTitle"
                  Background="{Binding Text, Converter={StaticResource LibraryItemBackgroundConverter}, ElementName=tbTitle}"
                  Margin="36,4,18,14">

                <TextBlock x:Name="tbTitle"
                           TextWrapping="Wrap"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                           Width="130"
                           Margin="0,0,0,0.2"
                           TextAlignment="Center"
                           FontSize="18.667"
                           FontWeight="Bold"
                           UseLayoutRounding="False"
                           d:LayoutRounding="Auto">
                    <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform Rotation="-90" />
                    </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                    <Run Text="{Binding Title}" />
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
            <Grid x:Name="gridBooks"
                  Grid.Column="1"
                  Margin="0,0,36,0">

                <!--<local:BooksUC />-->

                <GridView x:Name="booksGridView"
                          AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
                          AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                          ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource textbookTemplateSelector}"
                          SelectionMode="Multiple"
                          IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                          ItemClick="booksGridView_ItemClick"
                          SelectionChanged="booksGridView_SelectionChanged"
                          IsSwipeEnabled="True"
                          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
                          ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled="False"
                          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
                          ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled="False">

                    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <WrapGrid Orientation="Vertical"
                                      MaximumRowsOrColumns="1" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                </GridView>

            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

These solved the problem.